# what is "not in" in python?

Tags: javascript, python

I solve my previews issue myself, but there is only one block that i dont understand

```
if uus not in m.keys():
```

idk what that line means in python?
i want to wrote it on javascript but i cant couse i dont understand that loop.
can anyone plz explain me what that mean ?

if only know that m.keys() are in javascript Object.keys(lines)
So maybe somebody can help me with that

if(var uus  "not in"   lines), but im trouble with understanding what that "not in" means and how that is in javascript.

Comment: Define "the output is wrong".  What is the output?  What do you *expect* the output to be?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where does its behavior differ from what you expect?  Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for debugging.

Comment: i added python code to up, and i just asked is my translated code same as the python code?And if you find that place where im wrong then maybe you can tell me how do fix it or how do write that python lin ein javascript

Comment: That's not really how Stack Overflow works.  We're not here to translate your code for you or debug it for you.  If you have code that isn't working as expected, we'll be happy to help.  But you need to describe the way in which it's not working.  "This doesn't work, tell me what's wrong" isn't a valid description of the problem.

Comment: okey , i describe my problem then, wait.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the AND and NOT Operator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075652/using-the-and-and-not-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`not in` is the negative containment check. In this specific instance, it's checking that the object in `uus` is not contained in the container returned by `m.keys()`.

Comment: tnx, but can you tell me how this express is in javascript ?

Comment: You need to iterate over the container and compare each item in turn. But this is almost certainly not what you want. I recommend porting the algorithms, not the code.