# why does if not in(x,y) not work at all in python

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I want to select words only if the word in each rows of my column **not in stop words and not in string** **punctuation**.

This is my data after tokenizing and removing the stopwords, i also want to remove the punctuation at the same time i remove the stopwords. See in number two after usf there's comma. I think of `if word not in (stopwords,string.punctuation)` since it would be `not in stopwords and not in string.punctuation` i see it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075652/using-the-and-and-not-operator-in-python) but it resulting in fails to remove stopwords and the punctuation. How to fix this?

```
data['text'].head(5)
Out[38]: 
0    ['ve, searching, right, words, thank, breather...
1    [free, entry, 2, wkly, comp, win, fa, cup, fin...
2    [nah, n't, think, goes, usf, ,, lives, around,...
3    [even, brother, like, speak, ., treat, like, a...
4                                 [date, sunday, !, !]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import string

data = pd.read_csv(r"D:/python projects/read_files/SMSSpamCollection.tsv",
                    sep='\t', header=None)

data.columns = ['label','text']

stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def process(df):
    data = word_tokenize(df.lower())
    data = [word for word in data if word not in (stopwords,string.punctuation)]
    return data

data['text'] = data['text'].apply(process)
```

Comment: What do you expect the result will be when writing `(stopwords, string.punctuation)`?

Comment: You've created a tuple containing two elements, and only those two elements. `stopwords in (stopwords, string.punctuation)` would return `True`, for example

Comment: @Anwarvic i expected it to work like `data = [word for word in data if word not in stopwords and word not in string.punctuation]`

Comment: @G.Anderson yeah, i thought it would return the word that fulfills if the words not `stopwords` and not in `string.punctuation`

Comment: You should know that `string.punctuation` is a string of characters. `word not in string.punctuation` won't return `True` unless `word` is a punctuation character... is that what you want?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the only elements in that tuple are the variables/attributes/elements that you put in, `stopwords` and `string.punctuation`. There's nothing magical about a tuple that automatically expands the things you put inside it. Try printing the tuple and see what the output is

Comment: i know that. but since i tokenized it with the nltk then the punctuation character is separated from the word and become on it's own tuple in the list of words. and i thought i could remove it that way tho i'm not really sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to do it in one `if` statement, you could convert `string.punctuation` to a set and combine it with `stopwords` with an `OR` operation. This is how it would look like:

```
data = [word for word in data if word not in (stopwords|set(string.punctuation))]
```

Answer (score 1):

then you need to change

```
data = [word for word in data if word not in (stopwords,string.punctuation)]
```

to

```
data = [word for word in data if word not in stopwords and word not in string.punctuation]
```

Answer (score 1):

in function process you must Convert type(String) to pandas.core.series.Series  and use
concat

the function will be:

'
def process(df):

```
  data = word_tokenize(df.lower())

  data = [word for word in data if word not in 
  pd.concat([stopwords,pd.Series(string.punctuation)])  ]

  return data
```